# Can't Get the Value from Promise to Reducer

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, promise, async-await, reducers

I'm new to Promises and Async/Await ,i want to get an array of users from mongoDB, but when i get it, i receive it as a promise, and i want to use it in my reducer.
How can i do that.
Here's my Code:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {stitchClient} from '../pages/const'
import {RemoteMongoClient} from 'mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk';
import {DataBase} from '../pages/const';

const mongodb = stitchClient.getServiceClient(
  RemoteMongoClient.factory,
  "mongodb-atlas"
);
const db=mongodb.db(DataBase);
const collection= db.collection('User');

async function fetch(){

    return (
        collection.find().toArray()
        .then(items => {
        console.log(`Successfully found ${items.length} documents.`);
        localStorage.setItem('DataTable',JSON.stringify(items));
        return items;
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to find documents: ${err}`))
    )
}

async function GetDataFromFetch(){
    return await fetch();
}

const AllUsersReducer=()=>{
    console.log('My Data',GetDataFromFetch());
    return (GetDataFromFetch())
};

export default combineReducers({
    AllUsers:AllUsersReducer,
});
```

And here's the Log:
[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONJDu.png)

Comment: `return await fetch()`?

Comment: thanks, yeah a use `return await fetch()` , i'll edit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `async`/`await` in `AllUsersReducer`

```
const AllUsersReducer = async () => {
    const fetchData = await GetDataFromFetch()
    console.log('My Data', fetchData);
    return fetchData
};
```

`GetDataFromFetch` is async, wich means it's result will be a `Promise`. To get the result from that `Promise`, you need to use `await`.

Comment: @AbdellahBaybay If that solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and leave an up vote, thanks!